# how to use char values as signed variable

Tags: c++, variables, arduino

I am coding in arduino IDE, so basically C++. and I need to use a variable with only 1 byte for transmission purposes, but I need this to be signed.

More specifically I need to send an `int`(2byte) but this int has 2 values in it, one is a byte since I don't care of the sign since its always positive, but the other I need it to have negatives included.

I'm doing something like this.

```
turn = -120
int PromedioD_turn = PromedioD << 8 | (turn  & 0b11111111);
Serial.println("test");
Serial.println(PromedioD);
Serial.println(turn & 0b11111111,DEC);      //this is printing as 136
Serial.println(PromedioD_turn);
```

I cant understand why or how to solve this, I need to be able to send the value and also break it down later.

Comment: `int8_t` or `signed char`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bolov by using int8_t i could convert it bach to signed value

```
int PromedioD_turn = PromedioD << 8 | turn & 0b11111111;
Serial.println("test");
Serial.println(PromedioD);
Serial.println(turn);
Serial.println(PromedioD_turn);
Serial.println(int8_t(PromedioD_turn &0b11111111));
```